# Automatically update records in layer based on changes in another

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, attribute-joins, update, relationship-class

I am using QGIS and I have two layers the first one is `"Reading"` layer with the attribute details

[image: example1]

The second layer is `"Reading_History"` layer with the attribute details

[image: example2]

I want to use the expression functions in the default value field to take the last date reading from `"Reading_History"` layer attribute and update the `"Reading"` layer with it based on the "ID"` field.

[image: example3]

So when a new record for a specific `"ID"` added to `"Reading_History"` attribute the `"Reading"` attribute will be automatically updated to the latest `"Reading"`.
I wonder if there is such a function code to use in the expression calculator that may give the result above.

Comment: Use a virtual field instead of a default value. The "apply default value on update" setting works only when that layer updates, it doesn't work when other layers update.

Comment: Many thanks @csk. I will learn how to use it because I didn't use it before.